SENDER_ID_MISMATCH 403 error after migrating FCM APIs to HTTP v1
I'm having troubles with sending push-notifications after migrating to FCM V1
I did everything that migration docs say
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1

Created a completely new project
Created a json file for jwt token creation
Updated headers

Here is what my token creation code looks like (C#)
    async Task<string> GetAuthToken()
    {
        var firebaseCredentialsPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS");

        if (firebaseCredentialsPath != null)
        {
            GoogleCredential credential;
            using (var stream = new System.IO.FileStream(firebaseCredentialsPath,
                       System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream).CreateScoped("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.messaging");
            }
            
            return await ((ITokenAccess)credential).GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync();
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }

And here is how I send the request (Postman for better visual representation)


I am sure that the json file used for token generation belongs to a service account of the  project that is mentioned in the request URL (marked with red in the screenshots).
Token is added as a bearer token in Postman (check the screenshots)
What can be the cause of the issue?
Any ideas?

As Joe Spiro mentioned, there are two types of tokens
Access token and device token.
Both tokens should be generated using the same Firebase project.
Issue happened because device token was generated using another Firebase project.
But the error message is misleading and wrong by saying that sender id is wrong.
It's the recipient ID (device token) wrong, not sender ID.


EDIT: As clarified by @yurart, the issue in this case is that device registration tokens are specific to a particular project which has its own access token and trying to use a device token with the wrong access token results in SENDER_ID_MISMATCH

Sorry to hear about the confusion. Let me try to clarify this a bit:
To be clear there are two types of token involved in this case and you are using one for the purpose of the other. You are currently generating an access token as described in the doc you linked but to send to specific devices you need to Access the device registration token as described in the send documentation and use it (again the device registration token) in your send requests.
Hope that helps!

No, I am using tokens exactly as they supposed to be used. That's for sure.
Jwt token starts with 'ya'
Device token is another one.
I am not confused here
I have found a solution to the issue
Access token is used as a bearer token
Device token is used in the request body. That's right.

What's misleading here is the error message that says that sender id is wrong (meaning that access token is wrong) which is not.
The problem was in the device token (which is actually not a sender, but a recipient of the message).
So the problem happened because the device token was generated using another Firebase project, but used with the current Firebase project which is obviously wrong, but the error message is very misleading.
Your answer is actually helpful because you mention that another token.
